# Dynamic allocation of array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

i was trying dynamic allocation of array in C. here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{   
int *array=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));     
array[7]=7;     
array[8]=5;     
printf("\n%d\t%d",array[7],array[8]); 
}
```

I don't understand why array[7] gets printed and also why array[8] doesn't. Actually on using array[8],program stops responding on running the code. Why is this happening? when i have declared array of size 5 , shouldn't the program stop working after array[5] itself?

Comment: Your array is from `array[0] to array[4]` only

Comment: If your array only has 5 elements, why are you messing around with the 8th and 9th element? Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [UB(Undefined Behaviour)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means that **anything** can happen. Your program might crash, give a segmentation fault, wipe your hard disk or set fire to it , [make demons fly out your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) etc . And In C, [don't cast the result of malloc](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, `free` the memory you have `malloc`ed after its use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried int *array=malloc(sizeof(int)*5 ); and it gives me error on compilation - invalid conversion from void* to int*

Comment: You need `int* array` not `int array`. Also, which compiler are you using? I think it is a C++ compiler and not a C compiler.

Comment: That's what i am using `int * array=malloc(sizeof(int)*5)`, dont know why * didn't get displayed in the comment. M using Dev-C++.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling in C and not with a C++ compiler? I've never use Dev C++...